# CSS3 Marquee doesn't show all html elements in .marquee container

Tags: html, asp.net, css, css-transitions

My CSS3 marquee effect works as desired, however it doesn't cycle through all the elements contained in my `<section id="updates_display" class="marquee"></section>`.

I'm using ASP.NET WebForms, and I use Repeaters tied to a data source to render my `<a></a>` elements on `Page_Init`. The marquee would display my normal updates before I had added urgent and team updates. Now that urgent and team updates are created at runtime, it only cycles through 2 and never gets to the 3rd before starting over at the first element. I assume that if I added more this would continue to be the case.

How can I force the marquee to cycle through all `<a></a>` elements contained in the `section.marquee`?

CSS:

```css
section#updates_display {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    height: 25px;
    padding-top: 13px;
}

section.marquee {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

section.marquee a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transform:translateX(100%);
    font-size: 2em;
}

@keyframes left-one {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    10% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    40% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    50% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}

@keyframes left-two {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    90% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}

section.marquee a:nth-child(1) {
    animation: left-one 20s ease infinite;
}
section.marquee a:nth-child(2) {
    animation: left-two 20s ease infinite;
}

a.urgent_update {
    color: #FF3D00;
}
a.normal_update {
    color: #00E676;
}
a.team_update {
    color: #FFFF00;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="updates_display" class="marquee">
    <asp:Repeater ID="UrgentUpdatesRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="UrgentUpdatesDataSource">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <a class="urgent_update" href='<%# Eval("link") %>' runat="server" target="_blank"><%# Eval("Title") %></a>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
     <asp:Repeater ID="TeamUpdatesRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="TeamUpdatesDataSource">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <a class="team_update" href='<%# Eval("link") %>' runat="server" target="_blank"><%# Eval("Title") %></a>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
     <asp:Repeater ID="NormalUpdatesRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="NormalUpdatesDataSource">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <a class="normal_update" href='<%# Eval("link") %>' runat="server" target="_blank"><%# Eval("Title") %></a>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
```

Here are the contents of inspector in Chrome, which shows that there are 3 links contained within it, yet it only cycles through the first 2?

```
<section id="updates_display" class="marquee">
    <a href="Updates/Post.aspx?p=3" class="urgent_update" target="_blank">Urgent Test</a>
    <a href="Updates/Post.aspx?p=4" class="team_update" target="_blank">Team Test</a>
    <a href="Updates/Post.aspx?p=2" class="normal_update" target="_blank">Test</a>
</section>
```

**Edit:** I've played with it some more and discovered my issue lies with my `nth-child()` in my marquee CSS. I tried using `nth-child(even/odd)` but this caused all my even elements to display at the same time and odds at the same time, still working will update when I find the solution.

Comment: You've not told the third one to do anything in your css

Comment: @AndrewBone I discovered that just a second ago and included in my edit, I'm working on figuring out a dynamic way to accomplish this because I could have a dynamic number of elements to scroll through.

Comment: Are you opposed to using Javascript?

Comment: Not really, the other developer on this project isn't super keen on it so I was trying to keep it all css. He's a little old school and doesn't like the "complexity" that js presents for him I guess, in a way I understand where he's coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was in my lack of understanding how `@keyframes` was used, and what I was using it for. I based my original code off of an example that had a set number of elements to scroll through. My solution was to learn more about `@keyframes` and write my own animation. I opted to wrap my links in a div and apply the animation to the div. This creates a nice slow scrolling horizontal list of links. I may end up using `javascript` to count how many links are rendered into that div and then change my animation timing based on the count that way it will always scroll through them all at a slow rate.

CSS:

```
section.marquee {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

section.marquee_container {
    display: inline;
    width: 200%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
}

    section.marquee a {
        display: inline;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2em;
    }



@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        left: 100%;
    }
    5% {
        left: 90%;
    }
    10% {
        left: 80%;
    }
    15% {
        left: 70%;
    }
    20% {
        left: 60%;
    }
    25% {
        left: 50%;
    }
    30% {
        left: 40%;
    }
    35% {
        left: 30%;
    }
    40% {
        left: 20%;
    }
    45% {
        left: 10%;
    }
    50% {
        left: 0%;
    }
    55% {
        left: -10%;
    }
    60% {
        left: -20%;
    }
    65% {
        left: -30%;
    }
    70% {
        left: -40%
    }
    75% {
        left: -50%;
    }
    80% {
        left: -60%;
    }
    85% {
        left: -70%;
    }
    90% {
        left: -80%;
    }
    95% {
        left: -90%;
    }
    100% {
        left: -100%;
    }

}

a.urgent_update {
    color: #FF3D00;
}
a.normal_update {
    color: #00E676;
}
a.team_update {
    color: #FFFF00;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <section id="updates_display" class="marquee">
        <section class="marquee_container">
            <asp:Repeater ID="UrgentUpdatesRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="UrgentUpdatesDataSource">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a class="urgent_update" href='<%# Eval("link") %>' runat="server" target="_blank"><%# Eval("Title") %></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <asp:Repeater ID="TeamUpdatesRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="TeamUpdatesDataSource">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a class="team_update" href='<%# Eval("link") %>' runat="server" target="_blank"><%# Eval("Title") %></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <asp:Repeater ID="NormalUpdatesRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="NormalUpdatesDataSource">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a class="normal_update" href='<%# Eval("link") %>' runat="server" target="_blank"><%# Eval("Title") %></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </section>
    </section>
```